# Pandas: how to make algorithm faster

Tags: python, pandas

I have the task: I should find some data in big file and add this data to some file.
File, where I search data is `22 million string` and I divide it using `chunksize`. 
In other file I have column with `600 id of users` and I find info about every users in big file.
The first I divide data to interval and next search information about every user in all of this files. 
I use `timer` to know, how many time it spend to write to file and average time to find information in `df` size `1 million string` and write it to file is `1.7 sec`. And after count all time of program I get `6 hours`. (`1.5 sec * 600 id * 22 interval`).
I want to do it faster, but I don't know any way besides `chunksize`.
I add my code

```
el = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000000)
buys = pd.read_excel('smartphone.xlsx')
buys['date'] = pd.to_datetime(buys['date'])
dates1 = buys['date']
ids1 = buys['id']
for i in el:
    i['used_at'] = pd.to_datetime(i['used_at'])
    df = i.sort_values(['ID', 'used_at'])
    dates = df['used_at']
    ids = df['ID']
    urls = df['url']
    for i, (id, date, url, id1, date1) in enumerate(zip(ids, dates, urls, ids1, dates1)):
        start = time.time()
        df1 = df[(df['ID'] == ids1[i]) & (df['used_at'] < (dates1[i] + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=5)).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)) & (df['used_at'] > (dates1[i] - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)).replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0))]
        df1 = DataFrame(df1)
        if df1.empty:
            continue
        else:
            with open('3.csv', 'a') as f:
                df1.to_csv(f, header=False)
                end = time.time()
                print(end - start)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code

1. `zip` takes arguments that may be of different length
2. `dateutil.relativedelta` may not be compatible with pandas Timestamp.
   With pandas 0.18.1 and python 3.5, I'm getting this:

   ```
   now = pd.Timestamp.now()
   now
   Out[46]: Timestamp('2016-07-06 15:32:44.266720')
   now + dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(day=5)
   Out[47]: Timestamp('2016-07-05 15:32:44.266720')
   ```

   So it's better to use `pd.Timedelta`

   ```
   now + pd.Timedelta(5, 'D')
   Out[48]: Timestamp('2016-07-11 15:32:44.266720')
   ```

   But it's somewhat inaccurate for months:

   ```
   now - pd.Timedelta(1, 'M')
   Out[49]: Timestamp('2016-06-06 05:03:38.266720')
   ```

---

This is a sketch of code. I didn't test and I may be wrong about what you want. 
The crucial part is to merge the two data frames instead of iterating row by row.

```
# 1) convert to datetime here 
# 2) optionally, you can select only relevant cols with e.g. usecols=['ID', 'used_at', 'url']
# 3) iterator is prob. superfluous
el = pd.read_csv('df2.csv', chunksize=1000000, parse_dates=['used_at'])

buys = pd.read_excel('smartphone.xlsx')
buys['date'] = pd.to_datetime(buys['date'])
# consider loading only relevant columns to buys

# compute time intervals here (not in a loop!)
buys['date_min'] = (buys['date'] - pd.TimeDelta(1, unit='M')
buys['date_min'] = (buys['date'] + pd.TimeDelta(5, unit='D')

# now replace (probably it needs to be done row by row)
buys['date_min'] = buys['date_min'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0))
buys['date_max'] = buys['date_max'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0))

# not necessary
# dates1 = buys['date']
# ids1 = buys['id']

for chunk in el:
    # already converted to datetime
    # i['used_at'] = pd.to_datetime(i['used_at'])

    # defer sorting until later
    # df = i.sort_values(['ID', 'used_at'])

    # merge!
    # (option how='inner' selects only rows that have the same id in both data frames; it's default)
    merged = pd.merge(chunk, buys, left_on='ID', right_on='id', how='inner')
    bool_idx = (merged['used_at'] < merged['date_max']) & (merged['used_at'] > merged['date_min'])
    selected = merged.loc[bool_idx]

    # probably don't need additional columns from buys, 
    # so either drop them or select the ones from chunk (beware of possible duplicates in names)
    selected = selected[chunk.columns]

    # sort now (possibly a smaller frame)
    selected = selected.sort_values(['ID', 'used_at'])

    if selected.empty:
        continue
    with open('3.csv', 'a') as f:
        selected.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

Hope this helps. Please double check the code and adjust to your needs.

Please, take a look at [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) to understand the options of `merge`.

Comment: in this string should be not `select = select[chunk.columns]` and should be `select = selected[chunk.columns]`?

Comment: In output file I get `id`, that not in `buys`. It's connect with work of `merge`. I change it to `merged = pd.merge(buys, chunk, left_on='id', right_on='ID')` because it turn `KeyError`

Comment: @ldevyataykina Ah, yes, `select` is a typo; should be `selected` everywhere. I also accidentally swapped `id` and `ID`. (Updated the answer.) But I don't understand why you're getting `id`'s which are not in `buys` - it shouldn't happen. Maybe try adding `how='inner'` to merge explicitly.

Comment: Can you say, Where can I have a problem? I try to run this code with anither algorithm and quantity of ID is more, than quantity with this code

Comment: I can't understand, how it check data? If data in this interval, it add it?

Comment: If `buy['data']` not in file, but it's more, than `date_min`. Is it will be written to file?

Comment: `bool_idx` is a bool list (actually a Series) whose values are True if the date is in the interval. Then `merged.loc[bool_idx]` selects only the rows where `bool_idx` is True. If you have 2 identical `ID`'s in `chunk` and they appear in `buys`, then both will be matched and selected. (This can explain why the output is larger then `buys`.) But, when using `how='inner'`, nothing that is not in `buys` can appear in the output. Nor can it be in `merged`. I suggest that you take a small sample of your data, run the two algorithms on them, and if necessary compare step by step what they're doing.